# gstreamer rtpdepay error "Segment with non-TIME format not supported"

Tags: gstreamer

I've have a gstreamer pipeline that is playing back RTP stream received from udpsrc:

```
udpsrc port=6000 caps=\"application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H265, payload=(int)96, seqnum-offset=(uint)5331, timestamp-offset=(uint)2500093283, ssrc=(uint)2046637718, a-framerate=(string)1\" ! rtph265depay ! avdec_h265 ! videoconvert ! autovideosink sync=false
```

That works fine, however if I replace udpsrc with appsrc, it stops working. The only error I'm seeing is:

```
... Segment with non-TIME format not supported
```

non-working pipeline with appsrc:

```
appsrc name=appsrc caps=\"application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H265, payload=(int)96, seqnum-offset=(uint)5331, timestamp-offset=(uint)2500093283, ssrc=(uint)2046637718, a-framerate=(string)1\" ! rtph265depay ! avdec_h265 ! videoconvert ! autovideosink sync=false
```

Answer (score 2):

Turns out that appsrc needs to have its `format` property set to `time`.

Here is the fixed pipeline:

```
appsrc name=appsrc format=time caps=\"application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H265, payload=(int)96, seqnum-offset=(uint)5331, timestamp-offset=(uint)2500093283, ssrc=(uint)2046637718, a-framerate=(string)1\" ! rtph265depay ! avdec_h265 ! videoconvert ! autovideosink sync=false
```